# wrapping embed code in a link of one's choosing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Below is the "embed code" for a photo on Instagram (forgive me for using a photo of Kim Kardashian).

My question is: how would one wrap this embed code in an `<a>` tag (or some other tag) such that when one clicks on the photo, one goes to `www.google.com`?

```
<blockquote class="instagram-media" data-instgrm-captioned data-instgrm-version="4" style=" background:#FFF; border:0; border-radius:3px; box-shadow:0 0 1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.5),0 1px 10px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.15); margin: 1px; max-width:658px; padding:0; width:99.375%; width:-webkit-calc(100% - 2px); width:calc(100% - 2px);"><div style="padding:8px;"> <div style=" background:#F8F8F8; line-height:0; margin-top:40px; padding:50% 0; text-align:center; width:100%;"> <div style=" background:url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAACwAAAAsCAMAAAApWqozAAAAGFBMVEUiIiI9PT0eHh4gIB4hIBkcHBwcHBwcHBydr+JQAAAACHRSTlMABA4YHyQsM5jtaMwAAADfSURBVDjL7ZVBEgMhCAQBAf//42xcNbpAqakcM0ftUmFAAIBE81IqBJdS3lS6zs3bIpB9WED3YYXFPmHRfT8sgyrCP1x8uEUxLMzNWElFOYCV6mHWWwMzdPEKHlhLw7NWJqkHc4uIZphavDzA2JPzUDsBZziNae2S6owH8xPmX8G7zzgKEOPUoYHvGz1TBCxMkd3kwNVbU0gKHkx+iZILf77IofhrY1nYFnB/lQPb79drWOyJVa/DAvg9B/rLB4cC+Nqgdz/TvBbBnr6GBReqn/nRmDgaQEej7WhonozjF+Y2I/fZou/qAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC); display:block; height:44px; margin:0 auto -44px; position:relative; top:-22px; width:44px;"></div></div> <p style=" margin:8px 0 0 0; padding:0 4px;"> <a href="https://instagram.com/p/5Fo5nTuSz9/" style=" color:#000; font-family:Arial,sans-serif; font-size:14px; font-style:normal; font-weight:normal; line-height:17px; text-decoration:none; word-wrap:break-word;" target="_top">I&#39;m really so proud of our Kardashian Beauty @kbeautyhair hair products!!! I use them everyday &amp; my fave is the dry shampoo!</a></p> <p style=" color:#c9c8cd; font-family:Arial,sans-serif; font-size:14px; line-height:17px; margin-bottom:0; margin-top:8px; overflow:hidden; padding:8px 0 7px; text-align:center; text-overflow:ellipsis; white-space:nowrap;">A photo posted by Kim Kardashian West (@kimkardashian) on <time style=" font-family:Arial,sans-serif; font-size:14px; line-height:17px;" datetime="2015-07-13T19:30:05+00:00">Jul 13, 2015 at 12:30pm PDT</time></p></div></blockquote>
<script async defer src="//platform.instagram.com/en_US/embeds.js"></script>
```

When I wrap this code using HTML in `<a href='http://www.google.com'></a>` it doesn't work.

Is there some way I can layer the embedded image (or video) under a transparent image and make the transparent image clickable with the desired link address?

Answer (score 1):

```
$("body").on("click", "blockquote.instagram-media", function (e) {
    var $elem = $(this); //blockquote element

    window.location = "http://www.google.com";
});
```

OR

```
function wrapElements () {
    $("blockquote.instagram-media").wrap( "<a href='http://www.google.com'></div>" );
}

wrapElements();
```